# Generating java client libraries using endpointscfg.py?

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I tried to generate Java client libs from a python endpoint api using the following command from docs:

```
endpointscfg.py get_client_lib java -o . your_module.YourApi
```

they say in docs "replacing **your_module** with the name of the module containing your API class, and replacing **YourApi** with the class name of your API"

I have my api file as helloworld_api.py & the class in it as HelloWorldApi so I replaced as HelloWorldApi.helloworld_api I get error **ImportError: No module named HelloWorldApi**. would you please tell me what am I supposed to do ??

Comment: I solved the problem by reversing the helloworld_api.HelloWorldApi. thank you any way

Comment: this the following page
[link]https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/gen_clients